# Can Max duplicate multiple generators?

Tags: max-msp

Although I'm a beginner for Cycling '74 Max so I may not understand some of its concepts themselves, can I duplicate lots of generators (e.g. ~cycle) easily?

What if I want to run 100 ~cycle which sound randomly?
Even so do I have to create and visualize manually all generators in the patch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're new, it's best to start with the tutorials that are built into Max.

Read my [points on starting with max here](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/7531/n00b-to-max-msp?rq=1). As Bit Depth said, the Cycling'74 forum is the place to go.

That said, for your actual question you should look into using the [poly~] object.

Comment: Good point.  I hadn't thought about poly~.  Again Max comes with some excellent tutorials on using this object.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably get a better response to Max questions on the Cycling'74 forums, rather than here: https://cycling74.com/forums/#gsc.tab=0

Objects in Max can be easily duplicated using standard copy & paste functionality.  You can also duplicate object programatically using the javascript objects.  Look them up in the supplied tutorials.